# How to check Empty or Null HTML.Raw in Razor

Tags: razor

I have this field in my database of the type which hold HTML. By default it has the value:

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> <head></head> <body></body> </html>
```

Now I need to check if a user has added something to that field and display it, or else do not display this field at all.

I have tried things like:

```
@if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Html.Raw(@Product.Specificity)) == false ) { blah }
```

But that throws an error.

I can not use

```
@if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Product.Specificity) == false ) { blah }
```

because the field is not completely empty; it holds the HTML above...

Comment: What do you mean here: "the field is not completely empty; it holds the HTML above..."? Which values do you have in the DB field when you need and don't need to display it?

Comment: When I don't need to display it, it holds:
`<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> <head></head> <body></body> </html>` and when I do need to dsiplay it it holds something like: `<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> <head></head> <body> User input in the body field... </body> </html>`

Answer (score 0):

It's better to save only user input in the database and remove extra "wrapping" tags from it. But if you can't to do it you can simple compare your field value with "empty" value (you can save it somewhere as constant):

`@if (@Product.Specificity != Constants.EmptySpecificity) { ... }`